# wish to change appleid on new iphone whilst keeping original id on old phone

Tags: apple-id

I now have two iphones.  both use same email address and apple id.My wife is to use the old one. I wish to have a new appleid on one of them whilst keeping the original on the other. how do I change the appleid on one without changing it also on the other. ? I am worried that when I change it on the new one it will also change it on the old one.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you wish to spend the next year swapping back & forth between IDs every time there's an update to something, best practise would be to treat it as though you were selling it & wipe it completely, then set it up afresh with a new ID.

See [What to do before selling or giving away your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201351)

To get back any apps [though not their data] that were previously used on that phone, investigate [Family Sharing](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201060) which will allow any apps or music purchases to be shared between all 'family' members.

Answer (score 0):

I recently went through a similar process, resulting in 2 AppleIDs for myself, and a separate one for my wife.

You can "delete" the AppleId (iCloud ID) on one phone and then proceed to create a new one. You will not change the other phone, or any saved data in iCloud. I am pretty sure you will need a new email address for the new AppleId.

NOTE you will lose any data synced through iCloud on the new device (although it will still be on iCloud). Much of this can be saved and/or recovered - this is easier if you also have a Mac, but there are options to retain some (contacts etc) when you delete the AppleId, but not Notes.

You may want to retain the original for any purchases - activate Family Sharing.